# Meaning of these terms for stress fields?

Tags: field-theory, notation, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, stress-strain

I'm from a math & comp sci background and I'm currently looking at facture theory which deals with stress fields. Can someone explain to me what the following terms represent in the context of a stress field in a three dimensional system.

$\sigma_{xx}(x,y), \sigma_{yy}(x,y),$  and $\tau_{xy}(x,y)$

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of $\sigma_{ij}$ is force in direction $j$ applied in a surface whose normal is in the direction $i$. Therefore $\sigma_{xx}$ is an x-directed force applied in a surface whose normal is in the x direction, which we interpret as pressure. When $i\neq j$ we call it shear, but the idea is the same.

This drawing from Wikipedia might be helpful:

[image: Schematic of tensor components]

Comment: Why the use of $\tau_{xy}$ instead of $\sigma_{xy}$?

Comment: I guess it's just to separate things. All terms of the type $ii$ are pressures, and $ij$ are shears.

Comment: It's more common to say 'normal stresses' rather than 'pressures' for components 11, 22 and 33.   'Pressure' is usually taken to mean (1/3 of) the trace of the tensor, a.k.a 'hydrostatic stress'.   The use of tau for shears is an anachronism from the days when tensor notation was less common in engineering.